# How to add HTML ID to gwt tabpanel tabs

Tags: gwt, tabpanel

Anyone knows how to add an ID to GWT tab panel tab headings so that they can be used in Selenium like applications.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get to element, and set as property:)?

```
tagPanel.getElement().setAttribute("id", "myId")
```

Comment: thanx for the reply but I need IDs on individual tab headings..
|1stTab|2ndTab|3rdTab|